# Configuring JBoss in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss

I just started working with Java EE. Does anyone know what I'm missing here? Let me know if you need more information. I'm working with intelliJ and JBoss EAP.

> [2016-02-21 11:57:19,930] Artifact helloworld:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
>   [2016-02-21 11:57:19,931] Artifact helloworld:war: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"helloworld.war\"
>       Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class com.rd.helloworld.HelloServlet for component com.rd.helloworld.HelloServlet has errors: 
>   JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named null in deployment \"helloworld.war\""},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld.war\".beanmanager]"]}

Comment: "weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your persistence.xml is in the wrong place, hence the "Can't find a persistence unit named null in deployment"

Try copying persistence.xml in src\main\resources\META-INF